# Eclipse SWT Group Empty

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm Doing a Eclipse Plug-in which is a Multi-page-FormEditor.
On one Page i want some Data to be presented in Tables and Trees.
I want to split the Page vertical in to half's.
In order to achieve this i wanted to use Groups(Left Group,Right Group).

```
public class UtilityPage extends FormPage {


public UtilityPage(FormEditor editor, String id, String title) {
    super(editor, id, title);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) {

    ScrolledForm scrolledForm = managedForm.getForm();

    FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();

    Composite body = scrolledForm.getBody();

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();

    body.setLayout(layout);

    layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;

    layout.numColumns = 2;

    Group leftGroup = new Group(body, SWT.SHADOW_IN);

    Group rightGroup = new Group(body, SWT.SHADOW_IN);

    leftGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    rightGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    Label testLabel = new Label(rightGroup, SWT.CENTER);

    testLabel.setText("<Test>");

    Label testLabel2 = new Label(leftGroup, SWT.CENTER);

    testLabel2.setText("<Test>");

    leftGroup.pack();

    rightGroup.pack();

  }

}
```

My Problem is that this results in two Empty Groups without any Content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFPTA.png

This has happened to me multiple Times before, but i always worked around it.

But since i got no better idea how to accomplish my desired Layout, im here to ask if you guys have any other ideas. Or if you know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Group` extends `Composite` you must set a layout on the group.

Something like:

```
Group leftGroup = new Group(body, SWT.SHADOW_IN);

leftGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Group rightGroup = new Group(body, SWT.SHADOW_IN);

rightGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

When using layouts every `Composite` should have a layout. This includes classes such as `Group` which extend `Composite`.